# Permission denied (publickey). c : fatal: c : failed to establish ssh session (1)

Tags: command-line, ssh

I try connect to my job-site from different wifi, by typing:

```
sshuttle --ssh-cmd 'ssh' -r ubuntu@jumpy.[xxx].com 0/0
```

but I got:

```
ubuntu@jumpy.[my work name].com: Permission denied (publickey).
c : fatal: c : failed to establish ssh session (1)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you have a key pair set up for `ubuntu@jumpy.[xxx].com`? is the identity file in the default location on your local computer? If not, you may need to provide its location explicitly ex. `--ssh-cmd 'ssh -i path/to/identityfile'`

Answer (score 0):

For me it was working till yesterday and suddenly today I started getting the same error as you. I generated a new public key and it started working again.

`ssh-keygen -t rsa`